# SQL query to find number of trailing zeros across columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an sql query that given table of values of the form

```
| id | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 | day5 |
| 1  |  4   |  0   |  5   | 0    | 0    |
| 2  |  2   |  0   |  0   | 0    | 0    |
```

gives

```
| id | trailing_zeros |
| 1  | 2              |
| 2  | 4              |
```

that is, the number of consecutive trailing zeros in the days columns for each id (from day5 backwards)

Comment: On day 867820, is the column named `day867820`? [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL stands for Structured Query Language.

Comment: sorry, its mysql.  And yes the column names are in that form

Comment: Are there more than 5 days?

Comment: @user1893354 Then read the link I provided.

Comment: What if day2 had the value of "10".  Does that count as a "trailing" zero?

Comment: no, only counting zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible solution

```
select id,
   length(@k:=concat(day1,day2,day3,day4,day5&&1)) 
    - length(trim(trailing '0' from @k)) as trailing_zeros 
from days_table
```

Comment: What if day5 has a value of `1000`. This will return 3 even though it should return 0

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for something like this. Of course this is assuming you only have 5 days:

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE WHEN day5 = 0 THEN
    CASE WHEN day4 = 0 THEN
      CASE WHEN day3 = 0 THEN
        CASE WHEN day2 = 0 THEN
          CASE WHEN day1 = 0 THEN 5
          ELSE 4 END
        ELSE 3 END
      ELSE 2 END
    ELSE 1 END
  ELSE 0 END
  amount_of_zeros
FROM t
```

Awful, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I took the brute force approach:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id int, day1 int, day2 int, day3 int, day4 int, day5 int)
INSERT INTO #temp (id,day1,day2,day3,day4,day5) VALUES (1,4,0,5,0,0),(2,2,0,0,0,0)

SELECT id,
    CASE 
        WHEN day5=0 AND day4=0 AND day3=0 AND day2=0 AND day1=0 THEN 5
        WHEN day5=0 AND day4=0 AND day3=0 AND day2=0 THEN 4
        WHEN day5=0 AND day4=0 AND day3=0 THEN 3
        WHEN day5=0 AND day4=0 THEN 2
        WHEN day5=0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS ConsecutiveTrailingZeros
FROM #temp
```

Of course, if you need to count 100 as 2 consecutive zeros, this approach breaks down. And this is SQL Server syntax. May need tweaking for MySQL.

But yeah, I'm fairly certain whatever you're doing, your approach is sub-optimal.

Comment: What if day5 has a value of 1000000. This will return 5 even though it should return 0. Also note it is MySQL. Regarding your first approach, it seems you're overcomplicating it. Re-read the question

Comment: I see now. Description of "trailing zero's" wasn't clicking, but I understand now. Editing solution.

Comment: A lingering question, which description doesn't make clear, is: If day 5 <> 0, is the answer always 0? Or should the solution return the count of the LAST span of 0 values?

Comment: Let the OP answer that question

Answer (score 0):

A version inspired by @YaroslavPogrebnyak 's answer

1. It's `NULL` safe (if by any chance columns are nullable)
2. It doesn't break if values itself have trailing zeros (e.g. 10, 20, 300 etc.)
3. It doesn't use user(session) variables

```sql
SELECT id, CHAR_LENGTH(
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               CONCAT(day1<=>0, 
                      day2<=>0, 
                      day3<=>0, 
                      day4<=>0, 
                      day5<=>0),
               '0', -1)
           ) trailing_zeros
  FROM table1
```

Let's try it out:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, day1 int, day2 int, day3 int, day4 int, day5 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table1 (id, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5) VALUES
    -> (1, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0),
    -> (2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    -> (3, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000),
    -> (4, 2, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT id, CHAR_LENGTH(
    ->              SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    ->                CONCAT(day1<=>0, 
    ->                       day2<=>0, 
    ->                       day3<=>0, 
    ->                       day4<=>0, 
    ->                       day5<=>0),
    ->                '0', -1)
    ->            ) trailing_zeros
    ->   FROM table1;
+------+----------------+
| id   | trailing_zeros |
+------+----------------+
|    1 |              2 |
|    2 |              4 |
|    3 |              0 |
|    4 |              3 |
+------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/443b2/1)** demo